# IE11 Run time error: 429 ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, adodb

I re-installed IE11 on a 64 bit machine because it was frequently crashing (on a click event, I think). Now my javascript code
var oConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
fails with:
"Run time error: 429 ActiveX Component Can't Create Object."
It was working fine before!

See this posting:
http://mkksharepoint.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/run-time-error-429-activex-component.html.
I took the advice and traced the execution with ProcMon on a 32 bit laptop where the code works and on the 64 bit failure. I have some logs that I will post if anyone answers my problem.

It looks like the IE security zone settings might be causing the problem. I tested my code with VBA in Excel. This works fine. My problem is in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It's just a guess that might work.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex 
You might need to enable some settings for ActiveX in IE. I don't know if you already have done this. If so I can't help you further.

Comment: The code is in an html file on my local disk. The security tab doesn't include that option. You have to play around with the registry settings. Thanks anyway.